# Need to redirect user from .aspx page to MVC route url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As I am working on `Asp.Net MVC mixed mode authentication`, I need to `redirect` a user from `WinLogin.aspx page` to `MVC route url` after getting authenticated from NTLM windows auth.

(I have WinLogin.aspx page in the same Asp.Net MVC project application)

**I just need help on how to redirect user from .aspx page to MVC route url.** (By `.aspx.cs` code behind)

I have tried using the code below, but NOTHING worked.

**Code 1:**

```
Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");  // redirection NOT working, getting blank page with route url after redirection.
```

**Code 2:**

```
System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary routeDict = new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary();
routeDict.Add("controller", "home");
routeDict.Add("action", "index");
Response.RedirectToRoute(routeDict); // redirection NOT working, , getting blank page with route url after redirection.
```

Could you please provide me with your suggestions on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about sending them there via the site root?: `Response.Redirect("/");`

Comment: Why wouldn't Response.Redirect work? It's the same thing as the user manually inputting the URL in the browser. If "/Home/Index" works  through the browser (first thing to check, I think), there's no reason it wouldn't work through a Redirect. How about Response.Redirect("~/Home/Index") ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Thanks Very much, it's really working! I would mark as an answer if you would have posted it as an answer!! By the way, What If I want to redirect to specific url like.. /Product/List ??  How would I do this? I don't want my user to be on home page, I need to show specific page after authentication.. How would I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's my comment as an answer (wow I'm a rep whore):

Redirecting to the site root works like this:

```
Response.Redirect("/");
```

Why? Perhaps your routes are broken. /Home/Index should work if your routes are the default routes that I would have expected. However, if your default controller is not Home and your default action is not Index then it won't work... whereas the site root would (because MVC's defaults just take over).

Comment: Why my Response.Redirect("/Product/List") not working! Is there any way??

Comment: Your routes are possibly broken. Can you update your question (or maybe start a new one) with your routes?